# iOS7 - Navigation Controller - Custom Back Button

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I need to use custom Back button image for my new iOS 7 app. When I use Storyboard and add image by using Attributes inspector, this is what XCode renders for me:
[image]

Does anyone know why the Navigation controller behaves this way? I'm regularly putting @2x PNG image into Bar Button Item(under Navigation Item) in my Table View.

```
@interface MEDevicesViewController : UITableViewController
```

In my application, I use [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) and I have Table View within Navigation Controller. This is on my navigation controller.

Any help appreciated...

Comment: `@interface MEDevicesViewController : UITableViewController` has no relevance. Show some real code.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton * button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 51, 31)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self 
          action:@selector(backbtnpressed:)            
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButton  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;


-(IBAction)backbtnpressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```